# How to get past the Pre-Flight request in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

First of all before i opened this question i searched a lot and couldnt find a solution what i am looking for.. Thats why new question.

Before i ask my question, here are few things you need to know.

1. I dont have control over the server. (Yes Cross Domain).
2. i Have an chrome extension to bypass "Allow-Origin-Request". [Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) is the link. (And this plugin is works fine! Tested a lot.)
3. The server works great in Terminal by "HTTP" command and server itself has a web gui for testing purpose which works great.
4. I have JWT Token which needs to be added to request.

So here is my question, I need to add JWT Token in GET and POST. I added JWT in request Headers using two methods "**AJAX Headers**" and "**AJAX Beforesend**".

Below is the snippit which i tried using **AJAX Headers**

```
$.ajax({
        url: serverUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'JWT xxxxxxxxx'
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
            console.log(xhr.readyState, "Readystate Error");
            console.log(xhr.status, "Error Status");
            console.log(xhr.responseText, "Error Response Text");
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            console.log(xhr.status, "server status code");
        }
    });
```

and here is snippit which i tried to send using **AJAX BeforeSend**

```
$.ajax({
        url: serverUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','JWT xxxxxx');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, err) {
            console.log(xhr.readyState, "Readystate Error");
            console.log(xhr.status, "Error Status");
            console.log(xhr.responseText, "Error Response Text");
        },
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            console.log(xhr.status, "server status code");
        }
    });
```

And for both functions this is what sent to server and got response back. (Caputred using **WireShark**)

```
OPTIONS /somepage/ HTTP/1.1
Host: *(serverURL)*
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://evil.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/app/page1.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6

HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 05 Jan 2017 06:58:16 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS

{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

and here is the console log

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load "serverurl"/somepage/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
```

So what am i doing wrong in here? Both Terminal and Web Gui are working but not with my app. What should i do? I need to appened JWT token in request headers, so that i can fetch data from server.

Comment: You say you've tested the extension. Have you tested it **with an `authorization` header**? The description says *"Allows to you request any site with ajax from any source. Adds to response 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header"* which doesn't say anything about adding `authorization` to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` of the response.

Comment: clearly the site doesn't want your website accessing it's resources directly

Comment: If you want to disable CORS for testing purposes, Chrome has a `--disable-web-security` command-line option.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I think that disappeared a few versions back (though it could've made an ugly return)

Comment: are you sure `Authorization` is the header you are looking for? it's not `Authentication` or something else documented on the site that has no URL

Comment: @JaromandaX: It's certainly in Chrome 55, I just double-checked. (You have to also use `--user-data-dir` with it.) Can't speak to whether it went away and came back, but that would be odd.

Comment: ahhh, it's the `--user-data-dir` that you have to add to make it work!! I remember now

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes i tried with --disable flag, still same result.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes i am sure that is the header. i tried using command line as "http GET http://www.serverUrl.com/somepage/ "Authorization: JWT xxxx"" it fetches the data. but not with the app..!

Comment: Odd, perhaps the site doesn't want your website accessing it's resources directly - proxy the request via your server - the fact that absolutely no Access-Control-* headers are sent by the server suggests the server does not **allow** CORS - though I'm not sure why your little chrum addon, or the extremely dangerous command line options (note, options not option) don't help you bypass this security rstriction

Comment: @ EmJiMadhu: `--disable-web-security --disable-data-dir` disables the SOP entirely in Chrome. But that doesn't mean the server can't look at the request and still choose to deny it server-side. (The SOP is handled client-side, by the browser.) (And yes, as JaromandaX points out, it's a **dangerous** option. Don't forget you have it turned on and go surfing the web... :-) )